# Hitler claimed that the Jews sabotaged Germany. What did he think were the Jews' motivation for doing so?

Tags: nazi-germany, hitler

I'm guessing he thought it was all about money?

Another possible theory - he thought that the Jews thought that the Nordic race was a threat to them so they tried to bring it down.

Edit - to be clear, this question is trying to understand Hitler and the Nazis perspective. That they were wrong has been well established and is not a matter of debate.

Edit 2 - What I'm trying to figure out is hitlers thought process. The Nazis were obviously wrong, they said that 'Every great creation, idea, and artistic expression on this planet were brought forth by real man.' and that Jews aren't 'real man'. What about Einstein who invented the most beautiful theory in all of science? What about the numerous other Jewish scientists, mathmeticians, engineers, and nobel prize laureates? But more to the point, his 'ideology' was based on pseudoscience that has been proven to be wrong. Also based on consipiracy theories that aren't true.

Comment: Interesting question, but could benefit from more preliminary research.

Comment: I can't (at the moment at least) bring myself to actually build an answer quoting from [this letter of Hitler's, dated Sep. 16, 1919](https://www.historylearningsite.co.uk/nazi-germany/hitler-and-the-jews/). I think it nicely answers the question however - Hitler saw no reason to assign a motivation to the Jews, beyond his hate and spite of them for being different.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I'm jewish myself and very pro jewish. What I'm trying to figure out is hitlers thought process. The nazis were obviously wrong, they said that 'Every great creation, idea, and artistic expression on this planet were brought forth by real man.' and that jews aren't 'real man'. What about Einstein who invented the most beautiful theory in all of science? What about the numerous other jewish scientists and nobel prize laureates? But more to the point, his 'ideology' was based on science that has been proven to be wrong. Also based on consipiracy theories that aren't true.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace ok I think I see what happened here. The question was subtly edited to imply an entirely different thing than what I intended. My question was 'according to hitler that the jews were out to sabotage and bring down germany, what was their motivation for doing so'. The way the question reads now its giving much more validity to hitlers views. I have changed it back to what it was originally.

Comment: Jews had a lot of wealth and were a very convenient scapegoat and outlet of dealing with frustration and uniting Germans again a common goal on very desperate times. Actually I got a very interesting book in comparative history just dealing with the politics surrounding those events, but unfortunately it is in my home town and not with me.

Comment: @user3148057 Concerning the edit I made, sorry, my fault. I was paying too much attention to grammar, not enough to content - no malice intended here, I was just careless.

Comment: @LarsBosteen I thought you were a real nazi, turns out you were just a grammar nazi which is much better. jk. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: The question would benefit from some prior research, starting with e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_antisemitism and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisemitism and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryan_race

Comment: I'd close it for trivialism

Comment: @user3148057 Perfecting the phrasing of the question is one thing, the background "reasoning" you present in comments another, and one that might be beneficial to have in the question itself. Apart from carful phrasing, documented prior research is sine qua non for an answer as well, "guesses" will not suffice.

Comment: As far as I know cynical Nazis used the Jews as scapegoats as had been done for centuries, while sincere Nazis might have actually believed claims that Jews were really demons disguised as humans and the Jewish goal was the extermination of all humans starting with Germans, that the Jewish betrayal of German was done for the Evulz   .http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ForTheEvulz  or because Jews just could only do evil deeds without motivation.  And maybe some Nazis were in between and believed Jews betrayed Germany for ambition, as part of their master plan to conquer the world.

Comment: The fundamental problem with the question is that it assumes Hitler believed his own rhetoric.